# Terraria Server Hosting Problem

Tags: wifi-direct, firewall

I want to host a game on the same network to play with my friends. I want to use Wi-Fi Direct and Terraria for Android (of course) but when they connect to me I can join their servers but they can't join mine. Is there some sort of firewall blocking the game? I have an OnePlus 2. I also had this problem with my old phone (Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini LTE) Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the same ISP? Maybe the prevention of incoming traffic to you is blocked upchannel.

Comment: Well, since I'm using Wi-Fi Direct (which is like Hamachi) I don't use any kind of internet connection. Keep in mind that I can connect to others regarding if I'm connected to them or they to me through Wi-Fi Direct.